# Can "safe sleep" actually be disabled on a Mac Mini running Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, sleep, wake-on-lan

I find that wake on lan stop working after my Mac Mini (late 2012 model, running OS X 10.8.5) has entered safe sleep (which is 4 hours after sleep starts).  Because I often travel and want to remote into my machine, and because I'd rather not disable sleep completely, and because I haven't found any way to wake the machine remotely after it has entered safe sleep, my only option remains to disable it.  After reading through [this discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4934852), I have set up my power options thusly:

```
Active Profiles:
AC Power                -1*
Currently in use:
 standby              0
 powerbutton          1
 womp                 1
 autorestart          1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                30 (sleep prevented by )
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        0
 autopoweroff         0
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 standbydelay         4200
```

Notice that `autopoweroff` is set to 0.  Despite this, the computer still enters safe sleep and thus wake on lan stops working after a period of time (4 hours, which I believe comes from `autopoweroffdelay` of 14400 seconds).

Any ideas on why this is still happening, or what I can possibly do to rectify it?

**Update**: a related question is, what magic does the built-in VNC client (i.e. when you open safari and go to `vnc://whatever/`) do to wake the remote host up?  Apparently whatever it does appears to work with my configuration even though the magic packet sent through the router doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the pram and is the firwmare up to date?  (I just did a search on this issue and seems like other Mac Minis have the same problem)

Comment: Haven't tried resetting PRAM, I'll give that a shot.  Firmware is latest as of now (`MM61.0106.B03`).

Comment: I upgraded to Mavericks (10.9), and then later reset the PRAM, testing after each step.  Neither one fixed the problem.  I guess I'll just try bumping up `autopoweroffdelay` to some absurdly huge number to delay it as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Safe sleep](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11096) usually refers to hibernation mode, or to the hybrid sleep / hibernation mode that laptops use by default. In http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1757, "safe sleep" is used a bit ambiguously, but it seems to refer to the hibernation-only mode that a Mac can enter if [standby mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392) or the autopoweroff feature is enabled.

If you mean standby mode or autopoweroff, they should probably be disabled by `sudo pmset -a standby 0 autopoweroff 0`. Since in your case they are not, you could also try running something like `sudo pmset -a autopoweroffdelay 99999999`.

Relevant parts of the `pmset` man page:

```
hibernatemode takes a bitfield argument defining SafeSleep behavior.
Passing 0 disables SafeSleep altogether, forcing the computer into a reg-
ular sleep.

[...]

hibernatemode = 0 (binary 0000) by default on supported desktops. The
system will not back memory up to persistent storage. The system must
wake from the contents of memory; the system will lose context on power
loss. This is, historically, plain old sleep.

hibernatemode = 3 (binary 0011) by default on supported portables. The
system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage (the disk), and
will power memory during sleep. The system will wake from memory, unless
a power loss forces it to restore from disk image.

hibernatemode = 25 (binary 0001 1001) is only settable via pmset. The
system will store a copy of memory to persistent storage (the disk), and
will remove power to memory. The system will restore from disk image. If
you want "hibernation" - slower sleeps, slower wakes, and better battery
life, you should use this setting.

[...]

standby causes kernel power management to automatically hibernate a
machine after it has slept for a specified time period. This saves power
while asleep. This setting defaults to ON for supported hardware. The
setting standby will be visible in pmset -g if the feature is supported
on this machine.

standby only works if hibernation is turned on to hibernatemode 3 or 25.

standbydelay specifies the delay, in seconds, before writing the hiberna-
tion image to disk and powering off memory for Standby.
```

There might also be some bugs in the implementation of the autopoweroff feature in 10.8, or the answer to this question might be to upgrade to 10.9.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and relevant snippet from manpage.  Unfortunately, upgrading to 10.9 did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the app 'caffiene' which prevents all power management whilst activated via a toolbar icon at the top right of the screen. http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/